# Find form ID on a website and input value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I would require a bit of help finding a form id on a public website (http://www.medicines.ie/). They updated the site and the previous id no longer works since now there is no Id to be found. What I am trying to do is open this site with VBA, input the value from a specific cell in excel to a form (textbox) on this website and press the search button. I am using the code below:

```
Sub Medicinesie()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
IE.navigate "http://www.medicines.ie/"
IE.Visible = True

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    IE.Document.getElementById("input").Value = Range("spc")  '<---- spc is the name of the cell I am referencing 
    IE.Document.forms(0).submit

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

End Sub
```

Comment: <input _ngcontent-c5="" class="search__input" placeholder="Search Medicine Database" type="text"> This is the HTML assigned to the field. These kind of things are easy to find if you use the developer tools of for example the FireFox browser

Comment: This is corerct, however from this information I am unable to give the right command in VBA to input the value into this field.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2007/using-vba-to-enter-data-into-an-html-form/41eb57b0-244b-4f61-80be-fb17033813d6

Comment: In the link you provided there is a solution if you have the name, tagname or id but here you only have class, type, placeholder and _ngcontent-c5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could take advantage of the URL construction at this website. URL is constructed: 
http://www.medicines.ie/medicines?page=1&per-page=25&query= + anything you would like to search in this database.

```
Sub MedicineS()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
Dim URL As String

URL = "http://www.medicines.ie/medicines?page=1&per-page=25&query=" & _ 
Range("spc")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate URL

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

End Sub
```

However if you still prefer to use your own way keep in mind that input you are looking for is 4th in the code so:
IE.Document.getElementByTagName("input")(3).Value
and the button is second so:
IE.Document.getElementByTagName("button")(1).Click

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works for me. I didn't notice the construction of the URL. Also thanks everyone for your fast response and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

With [selenium vba wrapper](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/) installed and adding tools > reference > selenium type library

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver '<== can change to internet explorer driver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get "http://www.medicines.ie/"
        .FindElementByCss("input.search__input").SendKeys "Aspirin" '<== Range("spc")
        .FindElementByTag("form").Submit
        Stop
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

**Example run:**

[image: Run]